# OSB Xquery :Date calculation

Tags: xquery, osb, soa-suite

All,
      I want to do a date subtract operation in Xquery, OSB 12C.Basically, have to check if an input date is < 6 months from the system date.

i.e- how to do in xquery : (SystemDate - inputDate)  < 6 months

Have went through:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13214_01/wli/docs92/xref/xqdtopref.html  but not able to compile any of the function listed there. Have also added the namespace in xquery. Do I need to add any library.

Any pointer is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

OSB has some extensions for dates, which you can [read about here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13167_01/aldsp/docs25/xquery/extensions.html#wp1297055).

But, you might not even need that for [simple stuff like you mentioned](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XQuery/Dates_and_Time).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I went through the link that you have mentioned above.But actually we need the year-month duration from the given date to current.whatever you are mentioned is correct only in case of taking the date/month/year portion from the given date as string/xs:date. Hope you got the query now.

Comment: Dude I'm not going to to your job for you; going from here to a solution is 30 seconds on Google and high-school level programming skill.

Comment: Cool dude..your answer didn't make any sound in my code.

Answer (score 0):

All,
  Issue got resolved.Please find the link for the  logic:`http://developer.marklogic.com/pipermail/general/2015-February/016462.html`

Comment: Pretty sure that link bears no resemblance to the problem you described, but I'm happy if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Subtracting dates give you dayTimeDuration in XQuery.

Following code is a simple and accurate way to check time intervals.

```
days-from-duration(fn:current-date() - $inputDate) < 180
```

180 is number of days you need to validate.